How to implement a Small language model? using gemma2:2b
I am trying to implement a Small Language Model using Gemma2:2b. Based on research I have done so far, I understand small language models, which are quantized versions of LLM like Gemma2b, can be executed on edge devices as they don't need GPU power like high end LLMs.
My use is to train a SLM on call center QA, consider a TV support call center, where there could be many issues raised by customer like TV demo needed, Remote not working after they receive new tv, I am trying to use SLM to respond to such queries from customer.
I have installed Gemma2:2b using Ollama on my local machine and trying out the following code I got from Chatgpt.

from datasets import Dataset

data = {
   "scenario": ["installation_support", "feature_demos", "missing_remote", "non_working_remote"],
   "customer_query": [
       "I purchased a TV, need installation support.",
       "Can I get a demo of the TV features?",
       "My TV remote is missing.",
       "The remote control is not working."
   ],
   "agent_response": [
       "Sure, let me get your availability and book a support session.",
       "I can schedule a demo for you. When are you available?",
       "I'll create a complaint ticket for the missing remote.",
       "Let's try some troubleshooting steps. If it still doesn't work, I'll arrange a demo session."
   ]
}

dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data)


# Load pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = "gemma2:2b" #"google/gemma2:2b"  # Choose a model with less than 3B parameters
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Tokenize the dataset
def tokenize_function(examples):
   return tokenizer(examples['customer_query'], text_target=examples['agent_response'], truncation=True)

tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
   output_dir="./slm_gemma_tv",
   per_device_train_batch_size=4,
   num_train_epochs=3,
   save_steps=10_000,
   save_total_limit=2,
)

# Create Trainer instance
trainer = Trainer(
   model=model,
   args=training_args,
   train_dataset=tokenized_dataset,
)

# Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()```

But getting following error, please suggest if this is better approach or any other approach which is feasible for my requirement.

```raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Incorrect path_or_model_id: 'gemma2:2b'. Please provide either the path to a local folder or the repo_id of a model on the Hub.```



